# Deploy an ASP.NET Core app targeting a new version of .NET to an existing Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an existing Azure App Service running on ASP.NET Core 3.x. I have upgraded the application to today’s release of [ASP.NET Core 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/announcing-asp-net-core-in-net-5/). This works fine on my local IIS Express server. When I publish to the application to the App Service using Visual Studio 2019, however, I receive the following error:

> ## HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies
>
> ### Common solutions to this issue:
>
> The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.

With [detailed errors enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60839746/3025856), I get the following additional information:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version 
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found.

The following frameworks were found: 
2.1.20 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 
2.1.22 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 
2.2.11 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 
2.2.14 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 
3.0.3 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 
3.1.6 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 
3.1.8 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK. 

The specified framework can be found at:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=5.0.0&arch=x86&rid=win10-x86
```

I had understood that [ASP.NET Core 5 would be immediately available on Azure App Services](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/announcing-asp-net-core-in-net-5/#deploy-net-5-web-apps-to-azure-app-service-today). Am I missing a step? How can I publish an ASP.NET Core 5 web application to an Azure App Service? Or do I still need to wait until the .NET 5 runtime is available on Azure?

> *Note*: This question was originally asked for ASP.NET Core 5. However, this question—and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64777920/3025856)—remain relevant to ASP.NET Core 6 and ASP.NET Core 7.

Comment: FYI: I've encountered a similar issue when [upgrading a web application to ASP.NET Core 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69891486/3025856), and publishing to an existing Azure App Service. As the resolution below doesn't work, and the specifics of the error are a bit different, I've posted it as [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69891486/3025856). I'm linking to it here, however, for anyone coming across this post after today's ASP.NET Core 6 release.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from [the release notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/announcing-asp-net-core-in-net-5/#deploy-net-5-web-apps-to-azure-app-service-today) referenced, but in order to take advantage of the new [App Service Early Access feature](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Runtime_Support/early_access.md) ([announcement](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/11/10/Dot-Net-5-on-App-Service.html)), you need to *explicitly* configure your App Service to use the .NET 5 stack.

#### Configuring an *existing* App Service for .NET 5

To do this via the Azure Portal for an existing App Service, complete the following steps:

1. Go to the App Service you want to upgrade
2. Click on <kbd>Configuration</kbd> on the left-hand navigation
3. Click on <kbd>General Settings</kbd> in the  page-level navigation
4. Under *Stack Settings*, select <kbd>.NET</kbd>
5. Under *Framework Version*, select <kbd>.NET 5</kbd>

> *Note:* Technically, once you do this, you'll have the .NET 5 runtime installed and could switch back to e.g. the .NET Core runtime stack. Doing so, however, would prevent you from gaining early access to subsequent updates to .NET, so I wouldn't recommend it.

> *Note:* For ASP.NET Core 6, this option is now labeled ".NET 6 (LTS)". For ASP.NET Core 7, this option is now labeled ".NET 7 (STS)".

#### Configuring a *new* App Service for .NET 5

This opt-in for the App Service Early Access is far more explicit when configuring a new App Service via the Azure Portal. In that case, when creating an App Service, you'll be prompted to select the *Runtime stack*, under which .NET 5 is explicitly labeled as *.NET 5 (Early Access)*.

> *Note:* If you already have another App Service configured to use App Service Early Access on the same App Service Plan, then the .NET 5 runtime will already be installed and available. This is because .NET runtimes are shared between App Services on the same App Service Plan.

> *Note:* For ASP.NET Core 6, this option is now labeled ".NET 6 (LTS)". For ASP.NET Core 7, this option is now labeled ".NET 7 (STS)".

#### Visual Studio publishing warnings

Even with the Early Access feature, you *may* still receive the following warning when publishing from Visual Studio 2019 16.8, assuming you have version compatibility checks enabled:

> Your application requires the .NET Core 5.0.0 runtime, but Microsoft Azure App Service only supports the following versions: 2.1.20, 2.1.22, 2.2.11, 2.2.14, 3.0.3, 3.1.6, and 3.1.8.

Despite that, once you publish everything should work, even if you're using the *Framework-dependent* deployment mode.

#### Application Insights

As a word of warning: The current implementation of [the App Services Early Access feature doesn't *yet* support Application Insights integration](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Runtime_Support/dot_net_core.md#net-5-early-access-limitations). I created an [issue requesting status updates regarding Application Insights compatibility](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/issues/61) back in November 2020, but I'm not expecting a resolution anytime soon: [a follow-up thread](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2119) was closed without resolution.

If you're still relying on the Azure integration of Application Insights, I recommend that you [migrate to the SDK implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core).

> *Note:* Configuring the Application Insights SDK in ASP.NET Core is dramatically simpler than it was in earlier versions of .NET Framework, and requires far less boilerplate code.

#### Alternatives

As an alternative, you can instead choose to deploy using the *Self Contained* deployment mode in your publishing profile (`*.pubxml`). This was the approach required for new releases of .NET Core on Azure App Services prior to .NET 5, and it continues to be supported today.

Comment: Everything was fine on .NET Core 3.1, I've updated to .NET 5 and the app service is broken. I've been trying to figure out what's causing the issue, digging through logs and diagnostic tools. Everything works as expected locally, but the app service throws 400 bad request (invalid host name), or returns 500.31 ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies (The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.). Any ideas? This is frustrating.

Comment: @Nexus: This might be due to a dependency still relying on an older version of the SDK, which could still be present locally or on a .NET Core configured App Service. If you haven’t already, I’d recommend [temporarily enabling `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60839746/3025856) to identify the _specific_ error detected. (That link—which is to a previous answer of mine—has more details on troubleshooting 500.31 on Azure, as well as a simple example.)

Comment: @JeremyCaney Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try and restart the app in Development mode. I've tried everything I could think of. Purged the wwwroot folder in Kudu and redeployed, deployed as a self-contained app, nothing worked. I've double-checked, the solution targets .NET 5 and all NuGet packages are up-to-date. class libraries target .NET Standard 2.1. I'll leave a reply if I could sort it out.

Comment: If it helps, for an existing app service, I made the changes to .NET / .NET 5 but then had to redeploy my latest pipeline release

Comment: FYI: It's been five months since the launch of ASP.NET Core 5.0, and Azure _still_ doesn't support the no-code configuration of Application Insights with Early Access. Given that, I'd recommend migrating to the [Application Insights SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core), which only requires a few lines of code for a basic server-side configuration.

Comment: FYI: I encountered a similar error when [publishing a .NET Core 6 application to an Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69891486/3025856). The approach in this answer is a _necessary_ but _insufficient_ solution for .NET Core 6. See [the new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69891486/3025856) for details.