# .Net 5 Azure App service missing dependencies

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-5.0

I've deployed my code to an app service using Azure Devops CI release agent. Once I browse to the App service, it shows this error, stating that .net 5 isn't installed, and lists what is.

'The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.'

[image: The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.]

This is what I have selected in the app service configuration, as it looks to be the only .Net 5 option.
[image]

Comment: Your project use .NET 5, but in settings you set .NET 5 (Early Access) which means Preview. I think this is an issue.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but that's the only option for .net 5 for any region. So I'm not sure what to do at this point, as MS says .net 5 is supported...

Comment: Try deploying your app as self-contained, not as framework dependent.

Comment: That may work, but it shouldn't have to be done?

Comment: @Hostel: _.NET 5 (Early Access)_ is the correct setting. It allowed access to .NET 5 on the release date, and will continue to allow access to upcoming versions of .NET as they become available.

Comment: @KryptoBeard: What SDK are you targeting in your `csproj` file?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, the Azure App Service could support the .Net 5.

From the error message, it is indeed show that .net 5 hasn't been installed in the app service.

I could reproduce this issue too.

[image]

But when I select the `.Net5 (Early Access)` in Configuration and Save it, it will update the web app settings. Then the website could run successfully.

[image]

From your screenshot, you already selected this option. You could try to restart the App service and check if it could work.

On the other hand, you could try to create a new App Service with `.Net5 (Early Access)`. Then you could directly use the App service with .Net 5.

[image]

Here is [a ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64777919/deploy-asp-net-core-5-app-to-azure-app-service) with the detailed  introduction, you could refer to it.

Comment: Are you sure that your application is .NET 5, not .NET 5 preview 7?

Comment: This app services was created brand new as a .net 5 app service. I've already tried restarting it and switching it again just in case to no avail.

Comment: Hi @KryptoBeard. It seems that the App Service hasn't downloaded the correct version. It downloads the version: .NET 5 preview 7. Could you share the App **Location** ? I created an App Service in `Central US` and it could download the 5.0.0 and run the app successfully.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT , This one is currently in USGov Arizona, could that possibly be the reason? I figured they would all have .net 5.

Comment: @KryptoBeard. This may cause problems, this region does not seem to be in my selection list. Can you try the Central US region?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT that doesn't seem to be an option in azure gov.

Comment: Hi @KryptoBeard. Thanks for your information. I am using [regular azure service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/azure-portal/). So it could work in my side. I think there could be differences between azure and azure gov, which will cause this problem.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue and my App Service's region in Azure is "UK West", so I'm not sure it's an issue with Azure gov. My project is targeting .NET 5.0, and I've configured the Web App's stack setting to .NET 5 (Early Access). When I run it, I get the exact same error as the OP. I've tried restarting the App Service and installing the ASP.NET Core 5.0 (x86) and (x64) Runtime extensions into it, all to no avail.