# Azure Web App suddenly throws HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies in .NET 6 (preview)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

I always used to deploy my Azure Web App during development. I suddenly updated my Visual Studio 2022 (preview) and after publishing the following error appears on the Web App:

```
HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies
```

How do I debug this further? I tried using the console in Azure Portal, but I could not find .NET 6 anywhere on the Azure Web App. Or actually how do I match the version on the web app with my own version?? I have no clue where the runtime is installed on the Web App as I've previously mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to go to the `project folder/bin/Debug` or `Release` according to your deployment selection in Visual Studio and then editing the `projectnamehere.runtimeconfig.json` file to the correct version number.

You can figure out the correct runtime version number by going to wwwroot (should be the default path by default) via Console in Azure Portal and then executing `dotnet projectname.dll`.

Case closed.

Comment: won't it get overwritten with each build?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview) .

> This release is not "go-live" and not intended for use on production
> computers or for creating production code. For instructions on
> installing and updating Visual Studio 2022, see this documentation on
> [updating Visual Studio 2022 to the most recent
> release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio?preserve-view=true&view=vs-2022).

For this error

```
HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies
```

You can try to Uninstall  all the EF Core `nuget packages` and reinstalling them.

For more information Please refer the below links:

. [500.31 ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies | MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0#50031-ancm-failed-to-find-native-dependencies)

.[Troubleshooting 500.31 ANCM on Azure App Service | SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839745/troubleshooting-500-31-ancm-on-azure-app-service) .

.[Early Access Runtime | GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Runtime_Support/early_access.md#early-access-runtime)

Comment: I've already tried settting the environment to development it seems to not throw any more exact errors... I tried listing packages or updating them with NuGet and it all failed... Even self-updating nuget.exe failed... I'm quite desperate at this point

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to delete the bin and obj folders in Visual Studio and rebuild the project.
Error went away after this.